# How to compute symbolic derivative of logit function?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, derivative

I'm trying to compute a symbolic derivative in R of the logit function, but I'm getting errors. When I run:

```
deriv(exp(-9.3 + 0.0146*x)/(1 + exp(-9.3 + 0.0146*x)), x)
```

I get:

> Error in deriv.default(exp(-9.3 + 0.0146 * x)/(1 + exp(-9.3 + 0.0146 *  : 
>     invalid variable names

When I tried setting my function to `logit1(x)` and ran:
`deriv(logit1(x),x)`
I similarly got:

> Error in deriv.default(logit1(x), x) : invalid variable names

as expected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to deriv has to be a *quoted expression*, and the second argument is a string giving the name of the variable.

```
deriv(quote(exp(-9.3 + 0.0146*x)/(1 + exp(-9.3 + 0.0146*x))), "x")
#expression({
#    .expr4 <- exp(-9.3 + 0.0146 * x)
#    .expr5 <- 1 + .expr4
#    .expr7 <- .expr4 * 0.0146
#    .value <- .expr4/.expr5
#    .grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 1L), list(NULL, c("x")))
#    .grad[, "x"] <- .expr7/.expr5 - .expr4 * .expr7/.expr5^2
#    attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
#    .value
```

Answer (score 1):

In `deriv(expr,var)`, `expr` needs to be an `expression` and `var` needs to be a `character`:

```
  v <- expression(exp(-9.3 + 0.0146*x)/(1 + exp(-9.3 + 0.0146*x)))
  deriv(v,"x")
```

You don't necessarily want to do any pre-simplification, but if you do, note that `1/(1+exp(9.3-0.0146*x))` would be equivalent and would give you a slightly simpler answer.